# How to pass a complex JSON attribute to a polymer component?

Tags: json, polymer

I am having no success in passing a "complex" JSON object to a component, from the main body of the app.

Passing an array, or a simple JSON object works as expected, this 3 followings forms work:

```
<x-name fullname='{ "first": "Bob", "last": "Dobbs" }'></x-name> 
<x-name fullname='["Bob", "Dobbs"]'></x-name> 
<x-name fullname='[{ "first": "Bob" }, { "last": "Dobbs" }]'></x-name>
```

However, if the object is a bit more complicated, like, say, embedding an array:

```
 <x-name fullname=
     '[ 
         { "first": "Bob",  "several": ["Bob", "Dobbs"] }, 
         { "last": "Dobbs", "many":    ["Bob", "Dobbs"] }
      ]'>
 </x-name>
```

What is the syntax to use? is it even possible?

For the first 2 forms to work, a hint as to be given (in the `created` function()), so that the component knows what format is expected. The third form works with an empty array hint. In the last form, how to give that hint?

Thanks guys.
F.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an extra comma at the end of your array item.  Note, you almost never pass data this way, you usually pass like this 
    data="{{myData}}"

Comment: You were right. The extra comma was the culprit. Creating a self answer to give a full working example. F.

Comment: Done, even though, the answer i gave is a more general guide to passing complex JSON, and use it in a component.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full working example:

From html body:

```
<social-bar sites='[
        {"base":"http://www.facebook.com","path":"/me","icon":"post-facebook","extras":["extra1","extra2","extra4"]},
        {"base":"http://www.twitter.com","path":"/me","icon":"post-twitter","extras":["extra4"]},        
        {"base":"http://plus.google.com","path":"/gplusId","icon":"post-gplus","extras":["extra5","extra6"]}
    ]'>
</social-bar>
```

From the component (`sites` variable is declared as an attribute in component declarative definition, and initialized as an array in `created` method),

```
<template repeat="{{site in sites}}">
    <a href="{{site.base}}{{site.path}}">
        <core-icon-button icon="social:{{site.icon}}"></core-icon-button>
    </a>
    <template repeat="{{extra in site.extras}}">
        <h4>{{extra}}</h4>
    </template>
</template>
```

Hope this helps someone.
F.